# How to check whether a particular value exists in an array in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala

I have a matrix in terms of a 2D array and another 1-D array. I am taking one element from the matrix and checking whether it exists in the array. Following is the code.

```
val array_intrval = Array.ofDim[Int](10)
var joint_matrix = Array.ofDim[Int][Int](5)(2)
for(i <- 0 to 4) {
  for (j <- 0 to 1) {
    var a = joint_matrix(i)(j)
```

After this, I want to check whether a exists in array_intrval, if not add a in array_intrval and then check whether there are some elements which is less than or equal to a. If yes, also put them in array_intrval. If a does exists in array_intrval, skip a and check for next element in joint_matrix.

I am a beginner in Scala and not able perform this. Any help regarding this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: "I am a beginner in Scala and not able perform this." So you need to learn some stuff. Where exactly are you stuck here? Look at `find` (to locate `a`) and `filter` (to return other elements less than `a`). There are some ambiguities in your description - if an element is added from a previous iteration but also matches on this iteration, do you add it again?  If there are more than one element matching `a` do you add `a` multiple times? Note if you do this, then `array_intrval` may be too small

Comment: I just modified the question. _So you need to learn some stuff_ Obviously I am in the process. Thank you for the hint. I will check find and filter.

Comment: I assume you mean 0 to 4 and 0 to 1, as Scala has zero-based arrays.

Comment: _If a does exists in array_intrval, skip a and check for next element in joint_matrix._

Comment: Yes. sorry, didn't read the question closely enough.

Comment: Sorry It would be 0 to 4. I am modifying that in the question as well.

Comment: This is a very odd algorithm. What is it's intent? Consider the max value in  joint_matrix. When encountered, it will not be in array_intrval. So it will be added along with all other elements less than or equal to it.  But since it's the max value, that's all other elements. So `array_intrval` will always have all the elements of `joint_matrix`. Even if you only add the others if not present,it ends up as all distrinct elements of `joint-matrix`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation of [Array](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.2/scala/Array.html) class. You'll find many useful methods there. For ex., a method called `contains` can be used to check if a certain element exists in the array or not.

```
scala> val array_intrval = Array.ofDim[Int](10)
array_intrval: Array[Int] = Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

scala> array_intrval(1) = 2

scala> array_intrval
res1: Array[Int] = Array(0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

scala> array_intrval.contains(2)
res3: Boolean = true

scala> array_intrval.contains(0)
res4: Boolean = true

scala> array_intrval.contains(5)
res5: Boolean = false
```